# Java jsoup select contents

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I have a html file that contains many of the following code blocks:

```
<div class="f-icon m-item " data-ctrdot="60055294621"> 
 <div class="item-main util-clearfix"> 
  <div class="content"> 
   <div class="cwrap"> 
    <div class="cleft"> 
     <div class="lwrap"> 
      <h2 class="title"><a href="http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Sunnytex-Best-Selling-wind-proof-Soft_60055294621.html?s=p" title="Sunnytex Best Selling wind proof Soft Shell Winter Black Wool Coat" data-hislog="60055294621" data-pid="60055294621" data-domdot="id:2678,pid:60055294621,ext:'|n=2|s=p|t={{attr target}}'" target="_blank" data-p4plog="60055294621">Sunnytex Best Selling wind proof Soft Shell Winter Black Wool Coat</a> </h2> 
      <div class="attr">
        US $23.5-24.8 / 
       <em>Piece</em> 
       <em>( FOB Price)</em> 
      </div> 
      <div class="attr">
        500 Pieces 
       <em>(Min. Order)</em> 
      </div> 
      <div class="kv-prop util-clearfix"> 
       <div class="kv" title="Product Type: Coats">
        Product Type: 
        <b>Coats</b>
       </div> 
       <div class="kv" title="Age Group: Adults">
        Age Group: 
        <b>Adults</b>
       </div> 
       .... (many other stuff not shown here)
       </div> 
      </div> 
     </div> 
    </div> (end)
```

I want to extract all the links like `"http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Custom-3D-Made-Printed-Blank-Hoodies_60081368914.html?s=p"`.

I wrote:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(catUrl).get();
Elements products = doc.select("div.f-icon m-item").select("h2.title").select("a[href]");
for(Element prodUrl: products){
    System.out.println(prodUrl.html());
    itemUrls.addItem(prodUrl.html());
}
```

So basically I want to put all the product page urls into a hashset called itemUrls, but it seems that there's nothing in `products`. `Jsoup.connect(catUrl).get()` works fine and can return the web page to me, but the `select` method doesn't seem to work. Any input will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are used to describe `ancestor child` relationship, so `div.f-icon m-item` would represent `div` with `f-icon` class, and it would try to find `m-item` element in it.

In other words `doc.select("div.f-icon m-item")` is same as `doc.select("div.f-icon").select("m-item")` which can find only something like

```
<div class="f-icon">
   ...
     <m-item>...</m-item>
   ...
</div>
```

which is not what you want.

If you want to select element with two classes use `element.class1.class2` syntax.

So instead of

```
doc.select("div.f-icon m-item").select("h2.title").select("a[href]")
```

you can write it as

```
doc.select("div.f-icon.m-item h2.title a[href]")
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ div with two classes "f-icon" and "m-item"
```

Next thing is that `prodUrl.html()` will return you text which is used as representation of link like `foo` in `<a href="google.com">` [foo](http://google.com).

What you seem to want is value of `href` attribute. To do this use `prodUrl.attr("href")`.

So your code can look more or less like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(catUrl).get();
Elements products = doc.select("div.f-icon.m-item h2.title a[href]");
for(Element prodUrl: products){
    System.out.println(prodUrl.attr("href"));
    itemUrls.addItem(prodUrl.attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It is very helpful and it worked for me. But I still don't understand what "div.f-icon.m-item" means? The space in the original file means the div element has two class ids? And what's the difference between chaining the select method and your approach? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `select` is using CSS query syntax. For instance dot operator lets us find element with described class like `foo.bar` represents `<foo class="bar">`. If we want to find element which must have at least two classes like `<element class="class1 class2">` we can use `element.class1.class2` syntax. Now there is also `space` operator which describes `ancestor->child` relationship, which lets us find child that has some ancestor. If we write it like `select("foo bar")` it will first find all `foo` elements and then will search for `bar` inside them. It works same as `select("foo").select("bar")`.